# Select Hide/Show in WordPress Widget Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

So here is the problem, I've been trying to use jQuery to put a select hide/show field into my wordpress widget form. I have all of the fields in place, it's just the script that isn't working. Maybe I am doing something wrong, but I've searched and I can't find an answer, maybe someone can help.

```
<p class="dot-input-title">
        <label for="widget-bw_adspace-__i__-title">Title</label>
        <input class="widefat" id="widget-bw_adspace-__i__-title" name="widget-bw_adspace[__i__][title]" type="text" value="" />
    </p>

    <div class="dot-select-type">
        <select id="widget-bw_adspace-__i__-type" class="bw-select widefat" name="widget-bw_adspace[__i__][type]" >
                            <option value="upload" id="upload" >Upload Ad Image</option><option value="custom" id="custom" >Custom Script</option>          </select>

    </div>

    <div id="dot-input-upload">
        <label for="widget-bw_adspace-__i__-src">Upload Ad Image</label>
        <img style="width:100%" src="" />
        <input type="text" id="widget-bw_adspace-__i__-src" class="widefat bw_src" name="widget-bw_adspace[__i__][src]" value="" />
        <input type="button" class="bw_button button" name="widget-bw_adspace[__i__][src]_button" id="widget-bw_adspace-__i__-src_button" value="Upload" />
        <p>Use this field to upload or select and image from the media library.</p>

        <label for="widget-bw_adspace-__i__-url">Add URL</label>
        <input class="widefat" id="widget-bw_adspace-__i__-url" name="widget-bw_adspace[__i__][url]" type="text" value="" />
        <p>Add a URL to the selected ad.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="dot-textarea-custom-script">
        <label for="widget-bw_adspace-__i__-custom">Custom Script</label>
        <textarea class="widefat" id="widget-bw_adspace-__i__-custom" name="widget-bw_adspace[__i__][custom]" value="" col="20" rows="16"></textarea>
    </div>



jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('#dot-input-upload').hide();
    $('#dot-textarea-custom-script').hide();

    $('.bw-select').change(function() { 

        if ($(".bw-select").val() == "upload") {

                $("#dot-input-upload").show();
                $("#dot-textarea-custom-script").hide();

        } else {

                $("#dot-input-upload").hide();
        };

        if ($(".bw-select").val() == "custom") {

                $("#dot-input-upload").hide();
                $("#dot-textarea-custom-script").show();

        } else {

                $("#dot-textarea-custom-script").hide();
        };
    });

});
```

Comment: The jQuery works. Please post the relevant block of (generated) HTML

Comment: sorry about that, I edited the post above

Comment: Not the code, the **generated** HTML please - copy from the source of the page. It might be as obvious as I suspect, but I need to see those options.

Comment: You just updated that HTML from broken code to working code.  http://jsfiddle.net/U4464/1/ If the class name is in the correct place I need to delete my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ok it's here.

```
<select id="widget-bw_adspace-__i__-type bw-select" class="bw-type widefat" name="widget-bw_adspace[__i__][type]" >
```

You're selecting with `$('.bw-select')` but you've appended `bw-select` to the ID not the class.

*NB `$('#bw-select')` won't select that element because the ID is invalid, it having a space.*

Comment: I changed the class and still no response. Could it have something to do with the wordpress plugin api?

Comment: The code given, with this modification, produces no errors. Since you've updated it in the question this answer is no longer valid.

Answer (score -3):

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

change to

$(document).ready(function(){

or change all $ to jQuery ;